# Is there any way to get time from redis server with JedisCluster API?

Tags: lua, redis, jedis

I used Jedis(2.9.0) API in my application,I found that API not support TIME command of redis,how can i get system time from Redis server? or use lua script to do it? thanks in adance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though not supported by jedis yet, you can easily implement that with lua script.

like this

```
        String script = "local ntime = redis.call('TIME')\n" +
                "return ntime";

        ArrayList<Long> eval = (ArrayList<Long>)jedisCluster.eval(script, "1");
        System.out.println(eval);
```

The return list "eval" is just what time command returned, as redis website described:

> Return value
>
> Array reply, specifically:
>
> A multi bulk reply containing two elements:
>
> unix time in seconds.
>
> microseconds.

I use jediscluster, all eval method required "key" param, so I just input a random key "1", as this key is in fact useless. You can choose suitable client and method, but the code will be similar.

Answer (score 1):

ATM Jedis doesn't have a possibility to send raw commands to Redis and TIME command is currently not part from it. If you really need this you need to fork and implemented and afterwards send pull request.

Jedis goal is to be typed safe and simple. Adding new commands there is relatively easy.